# cyclic group with infinite order

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $A/B$ is a cyclic group with infinity order and $B$ is a normal subgroup of $A$. How do I show there is a normal subgroup of $A$ has index $i$, for all i greater than 0?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $A/B$ rather than $A\setminus B$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes

Comment: @ccom how about the positive case

Answer (score 1):

You have subgroups $n\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}\simeq A/B$. Take $C_n\subset A$ to be pre-images in $A$ of the subgroups $n\mathbb{Z}\subset A/B$. Then $A/C_n\simeq (A/B)/(C_n/B)\simeq \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has order $n$. Here by "pre-images" I mean pre-images under the natural projection $p\colon A\to A/B$.

Answer (score 0):

$A/B \cong ℤ$ is a free group, so the sequence $1 → B → A → A/B → 1$ splits. So you can write $A \cong B \rtimes ℤ$, taking $B \rtimes iℤ$ will then do.